# Make sure #bottom div clears absolute positioned boxes

Tags: html, css

jsfiddle.net/emcniece/u5Btt/3/

How do I get the #bottom div to clear the absolutely positioned .child divs?

I know there's got to be a thousand questions out there like this, I looked and tried stuff and didn't find a solution. Easy credits for somebody...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements are removed from the document flow. Since your .child divs are absolutely positioned, the #container div is treated as if it were empty and collapsed.

If you explicitly add height to your #container div, you will be able to 'clear' the #bottom div.

Comment: Cool, makes sense. Any thoughts on making the parent div height change as the child divs are made visible and hidden? So far it looks like jQuery...

Comment: Removing the position: absolute declaration from the .child divs will change the height of the parent div when any .child divs are added/removed. http://jsfiddle.net/pGMU4/1/

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as *clearing* absolutely or relatively positioned items in HTML+CSS. Clearing items is just for floaters. By definition, an item positioned *absolutely* does not interact with the positioning of other items. *Relative* positioning is the same, except that the offset point is not the origin (0,0), but rather the point from which it originally appears.